# Executing git log with pretty=format in groovy doesn't work

Tags: git, groovy

I need help with this piece of code:

```
def gitLog() { 
   return 'git log --pretty=format:\'* %h: %s \' master..HEAD'.execute().text.trim() 
}
```

I tried almost everything, but still nothing helps.
Command works just fine if you run it in command line, it also works fine if you remove format. How to make it work as is, what do I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to pass every argument separately:

```
def gitLog() { 
  ['git', 'log', "--pretty=format:* %h: %s", 'master..HEAD'].execute().text.trim() 
}
```

Try once again.

Comment: Now it works, thanks! Do you know why my version doesn't work, is it something wrong with the way execute works?

Comment: If it works, accept the answer please. When command is complicated in the meaning of signs used, it's better to pass arguments separately.

Comment: Accepted, but would be nice to get more info about what exactly is wrong with mine example, since it is part of the question. Thank you.